# Multithread Sqlite Community Xamarin issue

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Performing multiple queries using Mvvmcross Sqlite community plugin is causing my app to crash.

```
2015-03-26 11:03:53.594 App[986:5507] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.596 App[986:5507] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Community.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (intptr,string,int,intptr&,intptr) <0xffffffff>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.599 App[986:5507] critical:   at Community.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (intptr,string) <IL 0x0000f, 0x000c7>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.603 App[986:5507] critical:   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () <IL 0x00011, 0x000b3>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.606 App[986:5507] critical:   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand/<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__0`1.MoveNext () <0x00173>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.609 App[986:5507] critical:   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <0x000c3>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.611 App[986:5507] critical:   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <0x000a7>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.614 App[986:5507] critical:   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource>) <0x00037>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.615 App[986:5507] critical:   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery<T> () <0x000f3>
2015-03-26 11:03:53.618 App[986:5507] critical:   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query<T> (string,object[]) <0x000e3>
```

Is there any way to use Serialized Threading Mode with Mvvmcross SQLite plugin? Like it's being used [here](http://blog.thomasbandt.de/39/2433/de/blog/performance-optimization-of-sqlite-on-ios-with-xamarin.html) ? Thanks

Comment: Is it actually possible to use this SQLite plugin from multiple threads? Or do I need to write my own wrapper with locks?

Comment: What if I use separate connections for each of my threads, can it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Our team was just looking at this the other day.  Currently this is not possible.  You would need to contribute a change back to the project that allows you to set the sqliteConnection config.  At the end of the day our issue was a rogue sync process that was running multiple times at the same time.  Just be sure you actually need this before you proceed although it would be great for the rest of us to see how you do it!